# How to post an array of objects within another array of objects in node.js

Tags: node.js, arrays, postman

How can I make a post from postman to insert a new element in the students array

```
var students=[
    {
        "Name": "Analia Garcia",
        "id": 9876,
        "course": [
            {
                "order": 1,
                "courseName": "Biology",
                "approved": false
            },
            {
                "order": 2,
                "courseName:": "Analysis",
                "approved": false
            },
            {
                "order": 3,
                "courseName:": "O.S",
                "approved": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I already made the code as follows, but it has not worked for me.

```
 app.post('/students/',(req,res)=>{
    
    
       students.push({
            "Name": req.body.Name,
            "id":req.body.id,
            "course": req.body.course
           
        })
 
})
```

Comment: Your map function is doing "kinda" nothing you can just use `"course": req.body.course` can you show the error you're getting?

Comment: i think that res.body would be text and not object, maybe try `let body=JSON.parse(req.body)`?

Comment: You are missing a ' ] ' at the end, and you need to post the error, describe what exactly has not worked for you, since by the first look of the code, it seems like it should work.